# Animation on bumble look like when drag

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I would like some help on how I can achieve a Bumble-like animation when swiping, where an icon slides and scales in response to the user's movement, similar to the check or x icon.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/joQPd.png)